The payload part in a token is short by 2 characters
I'm trying to run an API POST method in my android application in order to get a token.
I tried running in Postman and it gives a token that has 636 characters, however it only gives me a token of 634 characters in my app.
Can anyone give me any idea how to fix this?
What I did:
@Headers({

        "api-key: ....",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @POST("....")
    Call<JwtTokenResponseModel> getJwtToken(@Body JwtTokenRequestModel body);

What I expect to happen:
In the response model I get a token that has a length of 636 characters, but I only get 634 in this token.
After checking I found out that the payload part of the token is the that is shortened by 2 characters.
Here's the Android Client Code responsible for generating the token :
        Call<JwtTokenResponseModel> call = apiService.getJwtToken(requestModel);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<JwtTokenResponseModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<JwtTokenResponseModel> call, @NonNull Response<JwtTokenResponseModel> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    jwtToken = response.body();
                    accessToken = jwtToken.getAccessToken();
                    Log.i("Info", "onResponse: " + response.code());
                    Log.i("Info", "onResponse: Expires In : " + jwtToken.getExpiresIn());
                    Log.i("Info", "onResponse: Token Type : " + jwtToken.getTokenType());
                    Log.i("Info", "onResponse: Access Token : " + jwtToken.getAccessToken());
                    Log.i("Info", "onResponse: Access Token's length : " + jwtToken.getAccessToken().length());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onResponse: Response successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onResponse: Response not successful or body is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JwtTokenResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Error", "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });


As the request with Postman works the problem seems to be on Android client side but your post misses the Android client code responsible for requesting the token. Please update your question with the relevant code parts and details about used library versions.

@Robert I just added the Android client code responsible for requesting the token. If there's anything more you need please let me know
